# php code in javascript with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I use a Ajax to fill a table with data.
One field contain date and I wanted to format it different with strtotim(). 
How can I run php code inside my JS? 

Here my Javascript snippet:

```
success: function (data) {

                var jobs = "<table><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Drive</th><th>DL</th>";

                for (i in data){
                    jobs = jobs + "<tr><td>"+ data[i].work_date+"</td><td>"+data[i].work_time +"</td><td>"+data[i].work_driveto+"</td><td>"+data[i].work_text+"</td></tr>";

                }

                jobs = jobs + "</table>";
                document.getElementById("jobs").innerHTML = jobs;
            }
```

Here is what I would like to have:

```
success: function (data) {

                var jobs = "<table><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Drive</th><th>DL</th>";

                for (i in data){
                    jobs = jobs + "<tr><td>"+ <?php echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime(data[i].work_date)); ?>+"</td><td>"+<?php echo date('H:i', strtotime(data[i].work_time)); ?> +"</td><td>"+data[i].work_driveto+"</td><td>"+data[i].work_text+"</td></tr>";

                }

                jobs = jobs + "</table>";
                document.getElementById("jobs").innerHTML = jobs;
            }
```

Comment: where come from `data` ?

Comment: Data comes from a mysql table, I use Codeigniter.

Comment: php does not work like that. php is run server side, and so it can't be run in your `success:function()`. You either need to return already computed data or use a js function to do the same thing.

Comment: ok but they don't come directly from MySQL, you must have something like MySQL -> PHP -> Apache -> AJAX Jquery -> JavaScript so there is a PHP stage where you can use the PHP function `date`

Comment: Convert first your date in your controller before passing in your javascript.